# Ayuda con la implementación de un between en mi query?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

Tengo un formulario con con 6 campos, dos de ellos son del mismo atributo, que es "fechaInicio", son del tipo Calendario, y uno es fechaInicio De: y el otro es fechaInicio A:, o sea un rango de fechas de ese mismo atributo "fechaInicio",
tengo el siguiente método en mi controller, que recupera los datos del formulario con el objeto consulta, dentro de ese objeto, tengo los atributos para recoger esos dos campos de fechaInicio, que son fechainicio y fechafin.

Ya que recuperé los datos,los pasa como parámetros al método del servicio para obtener el query, el método que hice en mi servicio recibe 5 parámetros

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/formulario", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String ejecutaConsulta(@ModelAttribute("consultForm") Consulta consulta, BindingResult result, Model model) {
 String descripcion = consulta.getDescripcion();
 String periodo = consulta.getPeriodo();
 String curp = consulta.getCurp();
 String rfc = consulta.getRfc();
 String fechInicio = consulta.getFechaInicio();
 String fechaFin = consulta.getFechaFin();

 List < Factura > lista = facturaService.obtenerLista(descripcion, periodo, curp, rfc, fechInicio);
}
```

Este es el metodo en mi servicio:

```
public List < Factura > obtenerlista(String descripcion, String periodo, String curp, String rfc, String fechaInicio);
```

y su implementacion

```
public List < Factura > obtenerlista(String descripcion, String periodo, String curp, String rfc, String fechaInicio) {
 return repository.findByParameters(descripcion, periodo, curp, rfc, fechaInicio);
}
```

Este es mi query:

```
SELECT F.CAMPO1, F.CAMPO2, F.CAMPO3, F.CAMPO4 
FROM FACTURA F
WHERE F.DESCRIPCION=?1  
AND F.PERIODO=?2 
AND F.CURP=?3
AND F.RFC=?4
AND F.FECHAINICIO=TO_DATE(?5, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que el query busque por esos filtros, por esos periodos de fecha que recuperé del formulario, QUE PERTENECEN AL CAMPO "fechaInicio
ENTONCES TENDRIA MI QUERY ALGO ASI:

```
SELECT F.CAMPO1, F.CAMPO2, F.CAMPO3, F.CAMPO4 
FROM FACTURA F
WHERE F.DESCRIPCION=?1  
AND F.PERIODO=?2 
AND F.CURP=?3
AND F.RFC=?4
AND F.FECHAINICIO BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Como le paso al query los atributos que recuperé del formulario, para el rango de fechas, del tipo "fechaInicio"?? porque ya no son parte de la Entidad, solamente un atributo que es el fechaInicio
Debo de cambiar mi metodo en el servicio para pasarle esos atributos de fecha?
es que no entiendo como hacer eso
alguien me podria explicar, por favor

Comment: Concatenando las `Strings` que recuperas del formulario una vez obtienes los datos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
@Query("FROM Factura f WHERE f.descripcion=?1 AND f.periodo=?2 AND f.curp=?3 AND f.rfc=?4 AND f.fechaInicio BETWEEN ?5 AND ?6")
List<Factura> findFacturas(String descripcion, String periodo, String curp, String rfc, Date fechaInicio, Date fechaFin);
```

Eso sí, antes tendrás que hacer, en tu código java (en el servicio, por ejemplo), la transformación del String que te representa la fecha a un objeto Date (asumo que, en tu tabla, ese FECHAINICIO es de tipo Date).

Y ojo que la consulta que te he puesto no es SQL, es JPQL, por lo que estás trabajando con tus entidades lógicas, no con la tabla directamente, así que los nombres de los campos en las condiciones han de coincidir con los atributos de tu clase.

Y como recomendación, **JAMÁS** uses concatenación de Strings para montar consultas contra tu base de datos, ya que te estás exponiendo a que te hagan un SQL Injection majo majo y te revienten la base de datos